# Strange transparent overlay Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Today when I started my computer I noticed on the desktop that I have a strange transparent overlay over all my windows in the middle of the screen about 500px x 500px, and all the things that I open is underneath, windows, browser or icons, nothing can be clicked,  and is invisible.

I made a restart too but it didn't help. How can I fix this?

A few screenshots from task manager:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Is it semi-transparent or completely invisible? Have you installed any software recently? Can you post a list of all process names from Task Manager? (you can skip duplicates)

Comment: Could you post a Image ? You probably installed some 3rd party application which starts on your PC and is always on top.

Comment: I updated my post with the screenshots, it is completely invisible, and I haven't installed any software recently

Comment: what is with rainmeter ? Could you close it and see if the same problem occurs ?

Comment: Does it also show up in safe mode? If it doesn't you can compare the running processes and try to find the responsible one.

Comment: Clover, DisplayFusion, HydraDM, Pokki and Rainmeter would be my prime suspects. Try shutting each of their processes down one by one and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I closed rainmeter and nothing happens.

I did not tryied safe mode yet, will try now. Thanks.

I closed them, the same problem still persist :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is being caused by a rogue process having a 100% transparent window then it might be worth trying [WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy-17).

It shows a list of all windows currently open (generally far fewer than the number of processes). It has a **Hidden Windows** option, but I haven't been able to find out exactly what difference it makes.

In theory you are supposed to be able to drag the Finder Tool over an area and it will show you what window is underneath. However, I tested an invisible window and it did not locate it. It did however show up in the list of windows.

If you suspect a window then you can right-click it in the listing and choose Close Window, Send To Back etc.

I haven't been able to test on a 64 bit system but the program seems to work on 32 bit Windows 7 at least.

[image: WinSpy++]

Comment: @Denees, so what was it?

Comment: A program that overlays on my screen :)